# how to map javascript object(converted from json webmethod) into array where js object having 1 property only and multiple values USING JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


      $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "default.aspx/getName",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d);
          var i = 0;
          arra = [];
          arra = $.map(objdata.data, function(n, i) {
            var tmp = {
              0: n.NAME
            }
            //          {
            //               0 : n.NAME
            //         }
            return tmp;
          });

        },

        error: function(result) {
          //error code
        }

      });
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <select class="form-control" id="Select1" name="dropdown">
            </select>
</body>

</html>
```

When received data from a webmethod than used JSON.parse(), and the data becomes a JavaScript object.
This is getting from webmethod

```
{ "data":[{"NAME":"XYZ"},{"NAME":"BAR"},{"NAME":" COM"},{"NAME":" AXA"},{"NAME":"CA CO MU"},{"NAME":"DE MUL FU"}]}
```

After that using json.parse ,but after that I am not able to return (normal)array  actually not able to use map array.

[jsfifddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ziel/uqp36b1v/1/)

Comment: refer this jsfiddle @Suren

Comment: i solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Get the data property from the returned object and then use the `map()` function to get the property `NAME` for each item.

```js
var data =  { "data":[{"NAME":"XYZ"},{"NAME":"BAR"},{"NAME":" COM"},{"NAME":" AXA"},{"NAME":"CA CO MU"},{"NAME":"DE MUL FU"}]};

var array = data.data;
var names = array.map(item => item['NAME']);

console.log(names);
```